# How can someone submit a comment when my site has no comment field?

Tags: comments

I was a bit surprised when I got a message that a comment was awaiting moderation on a website where I have I have turned off `Allow people to post comments on new articles` and there are no comment fields.

How can someone then submit a comment?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the hook `pre_comment_on_post` to exit early:

```
add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', '_scalar_wp_die_handler' );
```

This will not change the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have unchecked `Allow people to post comments on the article` on the `Options > Discussion panel`, then you have only disabled comments on future posts. To completely `disable comments`, you will have to edit each past post and `uncheck Allow Comments from the Write Post SubPanel`. Alternatively, you could `delete the wp-comments-post.php` file, or run this MySQL query, from the command line on a shell account, or using phpMyAdmin: `UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status="closed";`

Comment: Removing `wp-comment-post.php` might work for now, but it's a core WordPress file, and may be put back in a future update.

Comment: @PatJ we can Deny Access to `wp-comment-post.php` by `.htaccess` file below is the reference link for the same http://codex.wordpress.org/Combating_Comment_Spam/Denying_Access

Comment: That's definitely better than removing a core file.

Comment: So, if I create a script that tries to send a comment request to any page on my server, this will fall through even if I don't have a comment box? Currently there is a bug in v3.1 that does not allow me to show / hide panels using the Screen options - so I'll have to wait to uncheck the 'Allow comments'

Comment: PS. But it should be safe to run `UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status="closed";` on order to disable commenting for all pages / posts?

Comment: @Steven -- yes, that should be fine.  That'll close comments on all posts, which should allow `wp-comment-post.php` to dissuade would-be commenters.  (Note that the `wp_` part might be different in your DB, since you can change the database table prefix.  `wp_` is the default.)

Answer (score 0):

You may have turned off commenting on upcoming posts. The posts that already exists will not be affected. may be. You could probably search on how to turn off commenting in posts that have already been posted.

mbBlogging